# python IDLE shell appears not to handle some escapes correctly

Tags: python, escaping, windows-vista, python-idle

For example \b backspace prints as quad (shown as [] in example below).  But \n newline is Ok.

```
>>> print 'abc\bd'
abc[]d
>>> print 'abc\nd'
abc
d
```

Im running under Vista (pro), python 2.7

Ive tried googling this issue generally and in SO and cant find anything relevant, which seems odd and makes me wonder if theres some setting or other may be wrong in my setup.  Not sure what to look for.

Comment: You have adequately described your situation. Do you have a question?

Comment: Rob is right. That said, the problem might be in your shell and the encoding you happen to be using.

Comment: I'm also running Vista, but I'm not understanding your situation too clearly, could you please elaborate further?

Comment: @rob: The question I was asking is what am I doing wrong or what should I be looking for.  I believe that is how most people would interpret the concluding sentence of my post.  Do you have an answer?  :)

Comment: @Marcel: I am using IDLE with default encodings.  New line and tab escapes work ok, the others don't.   Is it reasonable to expect backspace, specifically, to work?   Is there a specific encoding I should be forcing?

Comment: @Yick:  what else do you need to know?  Do I infer that you have no issues with escapes?  Specifically backspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > > What am I doing wrong or what should I be looking for?
> > >       Is it reasonable to expect backspace, specifically, to work?

No, IDLE does not support backspace, nor carriage-return, nor formfeed, nor ANSI escape sequences.

You are expecting `\b` to move the cursor one cell to the left in IDLE's interactive shell window. It doesn't do that. IDLE does not support cursor addressing in its shell window, with the exception of newline and tab.

Comment: Thank you, Rob.  I guess the bad news is I'll have to do without, but the good news I don't have to delve into default encodings etc.  i had tried looking in such documentation as is provided but couldn't find that specific info on this nor did google help.  Is there proper documentation somewhere?  I'm wondering what I'm going to bump into next on IDLE.

Comment: IDLE is awful, you should stop using it entirely instead of wondering which of the awful things about it is going to affect you next.