# \b (backspace) not functioning correctly in Python IDLE, instead printing box character

Tags: python, backspace

I am writing a program for a simple loading animation, like the one you see while Window Command is processing something. Unfortunately, this does not seem to function in Python IDLE.
I discovered that the root of the problem was Python's `\b` function, which is supposed to backspace the character written before it. For some reason, this instead prints a character. When opened in CMD, it works just as its supposed to.

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Example of backspace not working in IDLE:
[image: img]

Comment: Idle does not support backspace...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20643196/12362709

Comment: `\b` is a character like any other, not a function. How that character is *displayed* is up to the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem and a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, it is not a good idea to insert images to display text. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer is that IDLE doesn't support `\b`, so it puts the box with a question mark. there is no way to fix this, other than asking Python to add support for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, IDLE had kinda been my standard in terms of running my .py programs. Maybe I should switch to PyCharm or something.

Comment: No, you should use IDLE, at least in my opinion, because is is the official Python IDE

Comment: @ArgusBrent I mean, you could just run `python3` from the terminal. But you'd have to install py.exe first since you're on windows.

Comment: @Bob It's not "official"; it's a simple REPL that ships with CPython and is useful for experimenting. Nobody expects it to be used as *the* way to execute a real script.

Comment: @chepner when I said official, I meant that it is included with Python

Comment: So is `pdb`, but that doesn't mean you should run all your scripts in the debugger. IDLE has a purpose: serving as an all-purpose runtime is not one of them.

Comment: I've already tried running programs in Windows CMD, and it allows the backpace to function properly, but lacks some other functionality that IDLE has

Comment: @theX, what do you mean by py.exe? Is this just Python?

Comment: @ArgusBrent , yes, It is just python. But for windows. I think it's either `python.exe` or `py.exe`. For windows, though.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE *is* functioning correctly; it just isn't working the way you *expect* it to. If your program requires `\b` to move the cursor to the left to allow other text to overwrite the previous character, then you need to use a terminal that supports such behavior.

Comment: Ok. Do you know any terminals (besides Windows CMD) that could perform this function?

Comment: Virtually any general purpose terminal emulator will likely do so.